# How can I replace the row# on a formula on multiple rows at once?

Tags: excel, replace, vba

So I have a sheet for tracking employee productivity. Each row represents a day and each individual has four columns.

Currently I have a row at the end of each week to pull an 'Average total' for each of the four columns. I noticed that it calculates incorrectly if the person is out for the day sick/vacation since a zero or 0% is calculated into the average. So I am trying to modify the formula to calculate a % based on the other average totals using Find & Replace.

My issue is that I can use a Wildcard to 'Find' `=AVERAGE(D***:D***)` but I cannot figure out how to replace the row number on my new formula without having to change the row number for each individual line.

Example:
`Cell D6` has formula as `=AVERAGE(D1:D5)`. I can 'Find' using `=AVERAGE(D***:D***)` without issues. I want to replace this with `=IF(ISERROR($B6/$A6),0,$B6/$A6)` but without having to enter a row number so that I can 'Replace All'.

This may be obvious to most but I did attempt to use the Wilcard in the 'Replace' field but it apparently does not function that way.
`=IF(ISERROR($B***/$A***),0,$B***/$A***)`. I also cannot just drag the formula down to the other rows because the formula is only once every 6-7 rows.

I hope this is enough information but if I'm missing a detail please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: type in the formula in the first row where it applies, and then just copy it downward.  As long as there is not a $ in front of the column or row reference letter/number the letter or number will change as it is copied

Comment: Without seeing your data layout, it is hard to know what exactly you need. 
 Can you show some sample data so we can further help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be easier with VBA.

Assuming, as per your example, the formulas to replace are in column D starting from D6, and that there are no other formulas present in this range that contain the word AVERAGE, you can loop the range, and if the string AVERAGE is found within the cell.Formula, it will replace with the new formula you stated. I have simplified your replacement formula as you only need an ISERROR.

The benefit of the R1C1 notation is you only need to state one replacement formula and it will apply correctly when placed in the cell (relative reference). This code would go in a standard module and you would press F5 to run.

Some further efficiencies by targeting only the cells in the range containing formulas with searchRange.SpecialCells method passing the type argument xlCellTypeFormulas.

Something like the following:

```
Sub ReplaceFormula()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change as appropriate to your sheet name

    Dim lastRowInColD As Long

    lastRowInColD = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set searchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(6, "D"), ws.Cells(lastRowInColD, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

    For Each cell in searchRange.Cells
        If Instr(1, cell.Formula, "AVERAGE") > 0 Then cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-3],0)"
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes!!! This worked perfectly! How have I never heard of R1C1?? I have spent hours searching online for the answer to my problem and finally gave in and came here to post for help. I have always been able to use the internet to teach myself specific macros or how to create Userforms with VBA but I underestimated it's awesomeness! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am so excited about this! I just used your code to change all of my '=IF(ISERROR=' that I had done manually before. I just did the entire sheet in a matter of a couple mins!

Comment: VBA is powerful and can simplify a lot of things.